# Testing the speed of uniformly convergence sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I have a statement that I believe to be true, but I struggle to prove. Let $f_n : D \to R$ be a uniformly convergent sequence to $f : D \to R$. Further let $g(n)$ be a positive sequence of real numbers, converging to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. If $|f_n(a) - f(a)| \in O(g(n))$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $a \in D$, then $ \| f_n - f\|_\infty \in O(g(n))$ as $n\to\infty$.

In other words: assume there exist $K_a, N_a$ such that $|f_n(a) - f(a)| < K_a g(n)$ for all $n > N_a$, then there exist $K,N$ such that $|f_n - f|_\infty < K g(n)$ for all $n>N$.

This seems a translation of “the convergence speed of a uniformly convergent sequence of functions does not depend on the point $x$”. I can make it work when $g(n)=1$ (it just descends from the definition of uniform convergence) but I’m stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is true, and your struggle with proving this outside of the case $g(n)=1$ hints at a counterexample.

You can consider $D=\{0,1\}$ and $f_n(0)=1/n^2$ and $f_n(1)=1/n$. This converges uniformly to zero since $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1/n \to 0$. Further, if $g(n)=1/n^2$, then $|f_n(0)| \in O(g(n))$. However, $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1/n \not\in O(g(n))$.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for your help.